# How to add dependency JARs for building Maven project in Jenkins?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml

My Maven project uses two dependency JARs which I built in my local environment. When I build the Maven project (clean install), it is failing. It is unable to find those two JARs.

How do I add those two JARs?

Those jars are there in my user account's .m2 folder. Build is running fine when done from eclipse.

Comment: Correct me if I understood it wrong. So, you can see the jars under your user account's .m2/repository folder. But is there a .m2 folder created for the jenkins user? Do you see the jars there?

Comment: What does the actual error message say?

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran Yes, you are right. They're there in the user account's .m2 folder, but not in Jenkins'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run a Jenkins server in your company, it would be good to also run a Nexus or Artifatory server that manages your Java artifacts (external and internal ones). First build your dependencies on Jenkins an deploy them to your repository. When Jenkins builds the other artifact, it can then draw the dependencies from your Nexus/Artifactory.

You could also use the Jenkins local repository for that, but in the long run it is better to have a proper Maven repository.

Comment: Is there any way to pass the local dependencies that are there in the local user's .m2 folder?

Comment: You can copy/paste them to the Jenkins local repository, but I don't recommend that.

Comment: What do you mean by "Jenkins local repository"? I don't have any .m2 folder inside the Jenkins installation directory.

Comment: Jenkins also creates a local repository in its user directory when you run the first build. But please, consider that your approach is highly unusual and against standard recommendations.

Comment: Note that I mean the user directory of the user that runs Jenkins, not the Jenkins installation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My C:/Users/Username/.m2 directory doees contain the maven artifacts. However, it seems Jenkins is not able to fetch them from there.

Comment: I was talking about the user that runs Jenkins, not your personal user name or directory.

Comment: Can you somehow specify a possible path? I am not able to find .m2 folder anywhere that is related to Jenkins.

Comment: The best way is to build the artifacts again on Jenkins (not just on your local machine). Then you can access them in further Jenkins builds.